# Least Squares Solution with Cross Products

Tags: vectors, least-squares, cross-product

Is there a way to find a least squares solution for a vector using a system of cross product equations?

For example $\vec{A}, \vec{B}, \vec{C}, \vec{D}$ are all known quantities in 3D space:

$$\vec{A} = [1,0,-.01]$$
$$\vec{B} = [.01,1,0]$$
$$\vec{C} = [1,.01,-.01]$$
$$\vec{D} = [-.01,1,.01]$$

These vectors are related by the following cross products where $\vec{E}$ is unknown.

$$\vec{A} \times \vec{B} = \vec{E}$$
$$\vec{C} \times \vec{D} = \vec{E}$$
$$\vec{A} \times \vec{D} = \vec{E}$$
$$\vec{C} \times \vec{B} = \vec{E}$$

$\vec{E}$ should be the same in each relationship and should be close to $[0,0,1]$

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What is known and what is unknown ?  You want a solution for what exactly ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.